# Stream query results with the native mongoDB driver for node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 100,000 records in a mongoDB collection and trying to retrieve them in a node.js application using the native driver.

I follow the example in [MongoDB doc for CursorStream](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursorstream.html) but get the error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Before this error I get many of these:

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.
```

here is my code:

```
var query = {...};
var fields = {...};
var options = {
    // "limit": 10
    //"skip": 10,
    //"sort": title
}

var stream = myCollection.find(query, fields, options).stream();
//  stream.pause();
var results = [];
stream.on('data', function (item){
    results.push(item);
    stream.pause();
    // Restart the stream after 1 miliscecond
    setTimeout(function() {
        stream.resume();
    }, 1);
});

stream.on('close'.....
```

The error occurs also when I don't define a listener for the 'data' event. 
but it doesn't occur if a pause the stream right after its creation.

The mongod version is v2.4.1
The node driver version is 1.2.x

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the problem is solved by setting a batch size in the Cursor Stream:

```
var stream = myCollection.find(query, fields, options).batchSize(10000).stream();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [setImmediate](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg) instead of setTimeout, to ensure outstanding IO operations can be flushed. See also https://github.com/ZJONSSON/streamz/issues/1

Comment: Thanks for the response. It didn't work. I noticed that even if I set the Tiemout to a large value e.g. X seconds  (i.e. keeps the stream paused for X second, resume it and pause it again for another X seconds), it starts the 'recursive' warning at the 101st iteration.

Comment: The problem is solved if a I set batchsize. Its also a lot faster than pausing/resuming the stream. I am not sure yet if there any implications with this.  var stream = deviceCollection.find(query, fields, options).batchSize(10000).stream();