# Memory leaks when iterating over mongo data stream using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, memory-leaks, mongoose

I am streaming in data from a mongodb collection, doing some calculations with the data at hand and then storing it back in mongo.  The process runs fine through the first 50k or so records and then after that it gets bogged down.  The first 50k records it seems to store 2-3k records per second, then closer to 2 per second.

```
var stream = Schema.find().stream();
stream.on('data', function (doc) {
  pauseStream(this);
  total++;
  OtherSchema.find().exec(function(err,others) {
   doc.total = others.data + doc.data;
   doc.save(function(err) {
     written++;
   });    
  });
});

function pauseStream(stream) {
  if((total > (written + 50)) && !timedout) {
    timedout = true;
    stream.pause();
    setTimeout(function() {
      timedout = false;
      pauseStream(stream);
    }, 100);
  }
  else {
    stream.resume();
  }
}
```

I am trying to control the flow to only 50 outstanding updates at a time, I have changed this number up and down, no change in where it all gets hung up. What am I doing wrong? Some sort of memory leak it seems like.  When I use memwatch the stats at 50k look like:

```
{ num_full_gc: 2368,al: 168610
  num_inc_gc: 55680,
  heap_compactions: 2368,
  usage_trend: 4177.7,
  estimated_base: 89033445,
  current_base: 121087440,
  min: 15957344,
  max: 366396904 }
```

Comment: I wonder if the setImmediate use would help - see one of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080650/stream-query-results-with-the-native-mongodb-driver-for-node

Comment: This seemed to speed up the way to 50k results but the results are still the same, I wonder if there is some closure/garbage collection issues going on.

Comment: Hi, just wondering to see if you have found the problem? tnx

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a [batchSize](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/) instead of pausing the stream yourself.

var stream = Schema.find().batchSize(50).stream();

Comment: This is definitely a cleaner solution then what I have, however the results still seem to be the same in regards to it bogging down after 50k records.

Comment: From http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#batchSize: batchSize only regulates how many
documents are returned for each batch using the getMoreCommand against the MongoDB server

Answer (score 0):

I suspect leak may be in your code. You use **doc** in internal callback closure.
Try to tell GC **doc** is not necessary anymore after it is saved.

```
OtherSchema.find().exec(function(err,others) {
   doc.total = others.data + doc.data;
   doc.save(function(err) {
     written++;
   });
   doc = null;//tell GC to free doc
  });
```

Comment: I had tried a lot of dereferencing things to force the GC to cleanup but it didn't seem to matter.  I also read that the GC should be able to pick up on this anyway.