# Node.js mongclient batchsize

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having problem with while trying to fetch  10,000 rows from mongdb collection using mongodb native client. It works upto batchsize of around 9700 records but returns no data for any larger batchSize. Here is the code snippet .. .. Any ideas what preventing it??

```js
app.get('/aps/allclients' , function(req,res) {

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  var collection = db.collection('allclients');
  collection.find({},{"batchSize":10000}).toArray(function(err, docs){ // works for batch size 9700 or less but not 10000
   
    res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));
  });
  db.close();
 });

});
```

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080650/stream-query-results-with-the-native-mongodb-driver-for-node

Comment: Can you subscribe to errors in your mongodb client? Anything in the logs? You might simply have too much data, either in the network stack or maybe in your node app. As suggested, try streaming the results if possible.

Comment: Limit you batch size of max 500! In practice a range between 200 and 300 is most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing your connection before the async `toArray` completes.

Put the `db.close()` call inside the callback instead:

```
var collection = db.collection('allclients');
collection.find({}, {"batchSize":10000}).toArray(function(err, docs){   
  res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));
  db.close();
});
```

That said, you shouldn't be opening and closing your `MongoClient` connection pool on each request. Just open it when you app starts and close it when you're shutting it down.